# What is a common-sensical approach to setting the boundaries of an interval?

Tags: terminology, bounds

As I am trying to present my results to a non-expert audience, I am wondering about what the most commonly used boundaries are for intervals. I mean specifically, which of the four versions explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals) is most aligned with a commonsensical way of thinking about intervals.

To give an example, if I said 10% of my sample consists of 20-30 year olds, would people commonly include 20 AND 30 or only take the interval of 20 to 29 (inclusive)? Or would it be the other way around 20-30 year olds including 21 and 30 year olds?

I know that what is "commonsensical" depends on who you ask but I'm sure that there is some tentative agreement of these boundaries.

Comment: Since this is more a question about the English usage of the word, you might want to check out this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/between-a-and-b-or-from-a-to-b/7890#7890

Comment: I suspect what is "common" varies by community.  Statisticians, for instance, are comfortable including the right endpoints but not the left (because that conforms with the conventional definition of a cumulative distribution function), but non-technical people tend to think in terms of initial digits and would group the 20 through 29 year olds, the 30 through 39 year olds, and so on, effectively including the left endpoints but not the right ones.